# Sum 1 to 100 int value and then float values in CUDA

Tags: cuda

This is what I tried for summing 1 to 100 for integers and I'm getting 0 as output.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <cuda.h>

__device__ int sum;

__global__ void kernel(){
    sum =0;
    atomicAdd(&sum, threadIdx.x);
    printf("%d",sum);
}

int main(){
    kernel<<<1,100 >>>();
    printf("%d",sum);
    return 0;
}
```

Also I'm not getting any clues to find the sum of 1 to 100 for float numbers as atomic operations are not supported on float numbers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In no particular order:

- You should not initialize `sum` in kernel code like you are doing.  All threads will do that, and there is no particular order of thread execution imposed by CUDA.  Do not assume that all threads will execute the `sum = 0;` statement before any thread goes on to the next.
- You cannot directly print a `__device__` variable in host code.  `nvcc` should be warning you about that
- You should be careful to use the correct `printf` format specifier
- You must wait for the kernel to finish, or force the kernel to finish, before printing the result.
- You can do `atomicAdd` on `float` variables.  See [here](https://docs.nvidia.com/cuda/cuda-c-programming-guide/index.html#atomicadd).
- I recommend doing proper CUDA error checking.

Here's a code that has those issues addressed.  Change the typedef from `int` to `float` if you want to see the float behavior.

```
$ cat t1895.cu
#include<stdio.h>

typedef int mt;
__device__  mt sum = 0;

__global__ void kernel(){


  atomicAdd(&sum, threadIdx.x);
  //printf("%f",(float)sum);

}

int main(){

  kernel<<<1,100 >>>();
  mt my_result;
  cudaMemcpyFromSymbol(&my_result, sum, sizeof(mt));
  printf("%s\n", cudaGetErrorString(cudaGetLastError()));
  printf("%f\n",(float)my_result);
  return 0;
}
$ nvcc -o t1895 t1895.cu
$ cuda-memcheck ./t1895
========= CUDA-MEMCHECK
no error
4950.000000
========= ERROR SUMMARY: 0 errors
$
```

Note that actually this code is summing the values from 0-99 not 1-100.  If you want to see the 1-100 sum, increase your threadblock size from 100 to 101 (i.e. summing 0-100), or alternatively do `atomicAdd(&sum, threadIdx.x+1);` in your kernel code.